# nextjs with docker. I connect to the website only with port 3000

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

In nextjs with doker I go to the website like this "site.com:3000".but of course I want to go to my site just by this link "site.com".I don't understand why 3000 is sucked at the end.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

DOKER-COMPOSE

```
    networks:
  docknet:
    external: true

services:
  nextjs:
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 5m
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        UID: ${UID}
        GID: ${GID}
        MYUSERNAME: ${MYUSERNAME}
        MYUSERGROUP: ${MYUSERGROUP}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/${MYUSERNAME}/client
      - /home/${MYUSERNAME}/client/.next
      - /home/${MYUSERNAME}/client/node_modules
    tty: true
    networks:
      - docknet
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.nextjs.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.postroyka.rule=Host(`MYwebsite.ru`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.postroyka.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.postroyka.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.ratelimited.ratelimit.average=30"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.ratelimited.ratelimit.burst=100"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.ratelimited.ratelimit.period=1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.postroyka.middlewares=ratelimited@docker"
      - "traefik.http.routers.postroyka.middlewares=https_redirect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
```

DOCKERFILE

```
    FROM node:alpine

ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG MYUSERNAME
ARG MYUSERGROUP
ENV MYUSERNAME ${MYUSERNAME}
ENV MYUSERGROUP ${MYUSERGROUP}

RUN apk add runuser
RUN addgroup -g $GID -S $MYUSERGROUP && \
adduser -S -u $UID $MYUSERNAME -G $MYUSERGROUP

WORKDIR /home/$MYUSERNAME/client
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD chown -R $MYUSERNAME:$MYUSERGROUP /home/$MYUSERNAME/client && \
exec runuser -u $MYUSERNAME npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Each application on your operating system needs to have a port - so does your nextjs application.
Browsers automatically hide ports 80 (http) and 443 (https), but they're present there.

If you still wish you hide your ports you could do that just by swapping your ports values with this:

```
ports:
      - 80:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your site is accessible at "site.com:3000" instead of just "site.com" is because you're mapping port 3000 of the container to port 3000 of the host machine in your Docker Compose configuration:

update as below

```
ports:
  - 3000:80
```